# Select from data from A table, with no match in B table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

i have example database, where i store relationships between males and females. The schema and some data are shown on image.

[image]

Is there a way to **select all man, which are not in BFF relationship**?
On example the answer will be **Bob, Charlie and Nick**.

I think, that actually im selecting data from A table without data from B table (with some condition). Is there way to achive this?

Comment: How is this question too broad? I think it's very specific. Duplicate sure, but not too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question of this type suggests `not exists`.  The tricky part is that the `not exists` subquery has a join:

```
select m.*
from man m
where not exists (select 1
                  from man_women_relationship mwr join
                       type t
                       on mwr.fk_type = t.id
                  where mrw.fk_man = m.id and t.name = 'BFF'
                 );
```

Comment: It works, thank you :) But is sad, that question for this query doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to sql, so I may be wrong. But this is what I would try:

select Name from Man_Women_Relationship join Type on Man_Women_Relationship.FK_Type = Type.ID AND Type.ID = 4

Comment: Sorry, that was for people who ARE in a BFF relationship, so I guess you would have to do the where not exists like Gordon did above.

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries can be slow and hard to read. You can use an outer join to avoid using a subquery:

```
SELECT Man.*
FROM Man
JOIN Man_Woman_Relationship mwr ON Man.ID = mwr.FK_Man
LEFT JOIN Type ON mwr.FK_Type = Type.ID AND Type.Name = 'BFF'
WHERE Type.Name IS NULL
```

This will get you all men who are in a relationship but not in a BFF relationship. In order to include men who aren't in any relationship, you need to `LEFT JOIN` the relationship table as well:

```
SELECT Man.*
FROM Man
LEFT JOIN Man_Woman_Relationship mwr ON Man.ID = mwr.FK_Man
LEFT JOIN Type ON mwr.FK_Type = Type.ID AND Type.Name = 'BFF'
WHERE Type.Name IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i dont think this should work, @Gordons answer fixed my problem :)

Comment: You don't think it works? Have you tried it?